# Cannot see initial page from nginx in other computers in same LAN on Fedora 35

Tags: nginx

I have installed it with command "sudo yum install ngingx" and its visible from computer host using its own ip in the browser, but in other computer in the same LAN and resolving ping it doesnt work and answers a timeout error. I know there is a /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file but I didnt see any valid configuration to resolve this (or I didnt search very well).
Machine has internet and resolves ping to other machines in lan
Could somebody guide me?
I use virtualbox to run Fedora
Thank you, here I left nginx.conf [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soOUF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was that apache is installed by default in fedora workstation and main page of nginx was showing apache as current web server, so any changes made in nginx wasnt being loaded. Solution: purge apache from system and reboot. Now nginx load as the main web server and changes made are applied

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you using bridge mode in virtualBox? If so and this is still  not working, check if Fedora has enabled the firewall by typing in a shell:

`systemctl status firewalld.service`

If active, check the zone where the main adapter is configured

`firewall-cmd  --get-active-zones`

Add ports 443 and 80 to the zone related to your interface (for instance FedoraWorkstation)

```
firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraWorkstation --permanent --add-port=80/tcp
firewall-cmd --zone=FedoraWorkstation --permanent --add-port=443/tcp
```

This should do the trick

Comment: I didn't need to enable port 443 to do this, but that resolved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

Apache (httpd) is installed by default in fedora. Apache is basically not allowing nginx to work properly.

### How to Fix

To fix the issue, run the following command and REBOOT THE COMPUTER:

```bash
sudo dnf remove httpd && sudo dnf remove httpd-tools && sudo dnf autoremove
```